# Google Ads Webhook integration for Lead Form Assets not sending data

Tags: google-ads-api

Campaign Details:

- Campaign Type: [Search, Display]
- Leads Generated: few (despite
  conversions showing in Google Ads interface)
- Webhook Implementation:
  [Custom code, Third-party platform]
- Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
  Checked the Webhook and key, sent test data, checked logs. Test data
  is landing correctly, Webhook is working correctly and logs there is
  nothing.
- Checked campaign status and settings (targeting, budget, etc.)
  Verified webhook URL and secret key are correct
  Tested webhook with Google's "Send test data" functionality (successful)
  Reviewed Google Ads Help Center and API documentation

Specific Questions:

1. Has anyone encountered a similar issue with lead form webhooks not sending data?
2. Are there any common pitfalls or configurations I might be overlooking?
3. Could my campaign type or specific lead form settings be impacting webhook behavior?
4. Are there any recommended debugging tools or strategies I can employ?

We sent test data from the lead form and that were landing.
We checked in our logs for the missing data, we were unable to find them in the logs.
We created a new webhook and key and are still getting this issue while the test lead lands in our system.